# Mistake in writing rule; Mail trying to move all junk mail to inbox

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

Today I wrote a rule in Mail to move email of a certain address from Junk to Inbox. While writing I accidentally forgot to change *If any of the following conditions are met:* to *If **all** of the following conditions are met:*, and now it's trying to move all the junk mail to Inbox, even those that have already been moved or deleted which leads to a bombardment of errors. I quickly fixed the rule, but the bad one is still going. I also tried to restart the app as well as the laptop to no avail. What should I do?

Comment: idk if it will help in this specific case, but if you launch the app from the Dock whilst holding Shift, it should open 'clean', with nothing left over from previous sessions. It's like throwing out the application Saved State. It doesn't change any other data.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but it's still going. Thanks anyways.